# Pushing items to the bottom in a vertical menu

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple menu in a sidebar.

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    <li class="bottom"><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
    <li class="bottom"><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The menu is obviously vertical. I'm using flexbox.

```
.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #222d32;
  transition: left 0.3s ease, width 0.3s ease;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex: 1;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu > li {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu > li.bottom {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/kpagcha/t5e1kLrd/10/) is a working example in JSFiddle.

I am trying to push those `.bottom` list items to the end of the sidebar menu. I saw a solution around here suggesting using `margin-top: auto` but that only does the trick for a single item. Not if you want to have multiple stacked at the end.

I tried using flexbox properties but that didn't work either. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/kpagcha/t5e1kLrd/13/) it is. The changes I introduced:

```
.menu > li {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  flex: 1;
  max-height: 30px;
}

.menu > li.bottom {
  align-self: end;
}
```

That's not working as intended. Besides I am not a fan of having to set a `max-height`. How can I tell flexbox to have the `li` container to adjust to the content's size but at the same time have those `.bottom` list items pushed to the end?

Of course I could use the `margin-top: auto` trip in a wrapping container but I am not fond of this solution. I would like to keep all list items at the same nested level.

Comment: you could just put margin top auto on only the top of your two bottom li: https://jsfiddle.net/xyb6prvz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have two `.bottom` elements you can't target them both to achieve this effect.

What you *can do* is target the first `.bottom` `li` that *follows* an `li` that does **not** have that class and apply `margin-top:auto`.

```
.menu  >li:not(.bottom) + .bottom {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```css
.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #222d32;
  transition: left 0.3s ease, width 0.3s ease;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex: 1;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu>li {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu>li>a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu>li:not(.bottom)+.bottom {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    <li class="bottom"><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
    <li class="bottom"><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code.

```css
.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #222d32;
  transition: left 0.3s ease, width 0.3s ease;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 1;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu li {
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu li ul { padding: 0 }

.menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu > li.bottom {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
        </ul>      
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```